# check_mk: How to install mk_docker.py on agent?

Tags: docker, check-mk

From Version 1.5.0 Check_MK can monitor docker containers directly over the Linux agents. I have upgraded to this version (server and agent), but there are no newly-detected services for docker.
I found this in the man page of the docker check:

> To make this check work the agent plugin {mk_docker.py} has to be
>   installed

How can I install mk_docker.py? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got the solution:

On the host (where the agent is installed) run

```
/usr/bin/check_mk_agent | grep PluginsDirectory
```

That dir is the one you have to copy the agent plugin files to.

Copy the plugins from your server to the host:

```
scp /omd/sites/yoursite/share/check_mk/agents/plugins/plugin.py root@yourhost:/path/to/pluginsdir
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [repository](https://github.com/zahaim/mk_docker-py) which contains instructions for installing mk_docker.py:

- `pip install docker`
- `pip install pyinstaller`
- Build it with `pyinstaller --onefile mk_docker.py`
- Put it to `/usr/lib/check_mk/local`
- Reinventory of check_mk host - and you should see new service
  (Container check)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But this mk_docker.py ist a 2-years-old script written by an external user. From Version 1.5.0 Check_MK can monitor docker containers directly. In my opinion there must be a mk_docker.py within the installation, but "find" cant locate this file

Comment: I guess you mean this one ? https://git.onesystems.ch/monitoring/check_mk/blob/master/agents/plugins/mk_docker.py

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download the "`mk_docker.py`"-Plugin from your `checkMK`-Site like this:

```bash
wget https://URL/yoursite/check_mk/agents/plugins/mk_docker.py
```